# Trouble configuring a router behind a router

Tags: networking, nat

I have a CISCO 2811 in the following configuration:

FE0/0 on the .1 network
FE0/1 on the .2 network
GW is 1.1 and is another router on the CM handling NAT DNS and DHCP.

From the 2811 I can ping the .2 and .1 networks and I can ping google.com

From host 2.50 on the .2 network, I can ping the .1 and the .2 networks but I cannot ping google.com

After researching this, I set nat outside on FE0/0 and NAT inside on FE0/1
and ip nat inside source list NAT interface FE0/1 overload.

This now allowed me to ping google from the host on the .2 network, but now I could not ssh to host 2.50 from the .1 network, however I can still ping.

I played with various ACL's but with no luck.

I tried posting my config here but I cant get the formatting correct

[image: Scenario 1]

[image: Scenario2]

I've concluded that I need a double NAT configuration. If someone could give me an example for the 2811 that would be great.

Comment: Tell us the routing you have set up on each router.  You shouldn't need any NAT on the 2811.

Comment: I would tend to agree about not needing NAT, but was the only way I got to be able to ping google from the host behind the router. I posted images of the 2 scenarios.

Comment: ip default-network 192.168.1.0
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1
ip route 10.5.5.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.2.2 .     I can ping through the router just fine, just not out past the GW router.

Comment: The 2811 router config is fine, it only needs the default route (though I am not clear what the 10.5.5.0 network is doing).  But your internet router needs a route pointing at the 2811 for the .2 network.

Comment: the 10.5 is another router but not an issue here. The internet router has the route to .2

Comment: Gateway of last resort is 192.168.1.1 to network 0.0.0.0

S*    0.0.0.0/0 [1/0] via 192.168.1.1
      192.168.1.0/24 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
C        192.168.1.0/24 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0
L        192.168.1.100/32 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0
      192.168.2.0/24 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
C        192.168.2.0/24 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/1
L        192.168.2.1/32 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/1

Comment: Any other suggestions? I'm out of ideas.

Comment: If everything on .2 can ping everything on .1 (including 1.1  - this is v.important), then the problem is likely the hide NAT rules on 1.1 not catering for both the .2 and .1 networks